# I am running zuul in a docker container, but I cant connect to it via postman on my local host (windows 10)

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, netflix-zuul

I have 3 services
zuul, eureka, and a rest service.
Running the code locally via springboot works and I can use the url

```
http://localhost:8080/account/bank/account/

But when I dockerise it
```

The eurka application.yml

```
server:
  port: '8761'
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-service
eureka:
  client:
    fetchRegistry: 'false'
    registerWithEureka: 'false'
```

Eureka local.dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:16.0.1_9-jdk-hotspot-focal

EXPOSE 8761

RUN mkdir /app
COPY target/eureka-service.jar /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/eureka-service.jar"]
```

The zuul application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-service
server:
  port: '8080'

eureka:
  client:
    instance:
      preferIpAddress: 'true'
    fetchRegistry: 'true'
    registerWithEureka: 'true'
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://172.21.0.2:8761/eureka
zuul:
  routes:
    account:
      path: /account/**
      serviceId: account-service
```

zuul local.dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:16.0.1_9-jdk-hotspot-focal

EXPOSE 8080

RUN mkdir /app
COPY target/zuul-service.war /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/zuul-service.war"]
```

the rest application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: account-service
server:
  port: '8082'

eureka:
  client:
    instance:
      preferIpAddress: 'true'
    fetchRegistry: 'true'
    registerWithEureka: 'true'
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://172.21.0.2:8761/eureka
```

rest local.dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:16.0.1_9-jdk-hotspot-focal

EXPOSE 8082

RUN mkdir /app
COPY target/account-service.war /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/account-service.war"]
```

I have two docker-compose files. Mainly through experimenting with trying to publish the ports.
Eureka and rest

```
version: "3"
services:
  eureka-service:
    image: eureka-service
    container_name: eureka-service
    build:
      context: ../../eureka-service
      dockerfile: local.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    networks:
      - banking-network
  account-service:
    image: account-service
    container_name: account-service
    build:
      context: ../../account-service
      dockerfile: local.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    depends_on:
      - eureka-service
    environment:
      - eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://172.21.0.2:8761/eureka
    networks:
      - banking-network

networks:
  banking-network:
    external:
      name: banking-network
```

zuul

```
version: "3"
services:
  zuul-service:
    image: zuul-service
    container_name: zuul-service
    build:
      context: ../../zuul-service
      dockerfile: local.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

    environment:
      - eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://172.21.0.2:8761/eureka
    networks:
      - banking-network

networks:
  banking-network:
    external:
      name: banking-network
```

when I run docker-compose up on both docker-compose
zuul and application is registered with eureka

But in postman when I run http://localhost:8080/account/bank/account/
it fails.

If I am correct I need to publish zuul-service port to the host.
But this is where I am having real problems

So following the docker docs
I run the following on the zuul docker-compose

```
docker-compose run --publish 8080:8080 zuul-service
```

running docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
ea2957b56646   zuul-service      "java -jar /app/zuul…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   gateway_zuul-service_run_c3988736de38
```

Zuul and account are registered
But neither URLs work

```
http://localhost:8080/account/bank/account/
http://0.0.0.0:8080/account/bank/account/
```

I created a simple health page on zuul. to see if I can connect to zuul

This url works, when its run from springboot

```
http://localhost:8080/gateway/health/
```

But neither works from docker

```
http://localhost:8080/gateway/health/
http://0.0.0.0:8080/gateway/health/
```

I thought publishing 8080 to my local host, would mean I could use localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions to debug the issue:

1. Put all services in one docker compose file and make sure they are on the same network
2. For defaultZone, change ip to eureka docker image name so instead of:

   defaultZone: http://172.21.0.2:8761/eureka

Try:

```
defaultZone: http://eureka-service:8761/eureka/
```

3. I’d try without `preferIpAddress: true` If you don’t have multiple replicas of your registered services
4. After Exposing zuul gateway port, check what routes are available at `localhost:8080/routes`

Comment: Thank you. but I found what the problem was/is because I was developing my code in increments. I thought I was rebuilding a new image. I was not, I removed the images, rebuilt and the code works.
I will never make that mistake ever again.
But I will try your service I prefer that than container IP.

Answer (score 0):

The code does work. I found out that because I was developing my code in increments. I thought I was rebuilding a new image. I was not, I removed the images, rebuilt and the code works.